# JSON populated form elements not filtering using angularJs filter

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

The Select element does get populated by the http request, but the options in the select element are not updating as the ng-model is changed.  I am new to angularJs so im assuming its a simple fix. I have tried many variation with no positive results.

```
    <script>
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {    
$http.get('http://graph.facebook.com/platform')
.success(function(data) {
})
        });
</script>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Search:
  <input type="search" ng-model="searchText" />

  <select>
    <option ng-repeat="item in data | filter: searchText">{{item}}</option>
  </select>
  <br>
     <pre>{{ data | json}}</pre>
</body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/C39yVDsG3OcfvwjVSxP9?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TarranJones, this Plunker should clear things up. Hard to give you a 100% clear answer without a look at your data. You should be able to figure it out from here.

http://plnkr.co/edit/UYm0SwtU6ePZkZLx2w2U?p=preview

To Answer your question in the comments I would replace:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.colors = [
    {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'white', shade:'light'},
    {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
    {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
  ];
});
```

With:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get('http://www.foo.com')
  .success(function(data) {
    $scope.colors = data;
  })
  .error(function() {
    console.log('My name is Error, now eat it!);
  });

});
```

Make sure to inject the $http.

Plunker here. http://plnkr.co/edit/UYm0SwtU6ePZkZLx2w2U?p=preview

UPDATE:

Tarran also ran into the problem of filtering a single returned JSON object from an API. Angular Filters can only accept arrays and so would not accept the object. In order for Tarran to filter the object he must first iterate through the object and store the object properties to an array. Once the array is then returned to the $scope you can filter the results. The plunker and code is provided below: http://plnkr.co/edit/9M3zZFN5jyV8w7fg7EE3?p=preview

Controller:

$http.get('http://graph.facebook.com/4')
    .success(function(data) {

```
    //CREATE AN EMPTY ARRAY 
    result = [];

    //ITERATES THROUGH THE OBJECT SAVING THE OBJECTS PROPERTIES TO ARRAY
    for (var i in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {

          //PUSHES THE PROPERTIES ONTO THE ARRAY
          result.push(data[i]);

      }
    }

    //SETS THE NEW DATASET TO THE ARRAY AND RETURNS TO $SCOPE
    $scope.dataset = result;

});
```

HTML:

```
  {{dataset}}

  <BR>
  <BR>Search:


  <input type="search" ng-model="searchText" />


  <BR>
  <BR>

  <select>
    <option ng-repeat="data in dataset | filter: searchText">{{data}}</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Hey great glad I could help. Mind checking me off as answering your question!

Comment: iI have added $scope.data = {} to the FetchCtrl function. now I need to populate it with the data received from the http request. Do you know how i could pass data from a child to the parent function?

Comment: I updated the answer above with how I would proceed.

Comment: Any chance your going to check off that I answered this one?

Comment: No problem, Your answers have been great.I just want to make sure I can get it to work before selecting your answer.

Comment: Tarran, the problem here is that filter was designed only to work with javascript arrays of data. The data returned by your api call is a json object. Reason being is that there was only 1 result returned by the api call. If for instance you had made a call to an api and it had an array of multiple objects, (mark zuckerberg, steve jobs, elon musk). You would be able to filter the results.

Comment: i have updated the plunker with a different dataset. is it possible at all to filter the nested objects of a single result . http://plnkr.co/edit/C39yVDsG3OcfvwjVSxP9?p=preview.  thanks for your help. I really want to get this working.

Comment: Tarran i've created a plunker that answers your questions, http://plnkr.co/edit/9M3zZFN5jyV8w7fg7EE3?p=preview. Make sure to check off that I answered this one. Ill also update the answer.

Comment: brilliant. it works perfectly. Thanks for going the extra mile.

Answer (score 0):

Try to init your data as object before all.

```
$scope.data = {}
```

Or in HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="FetchCtrl" data-ng-init="data={}; fetch()">
```

Comment: Of course, SCOPE. I have added $scope.data = {} to the FetchCtrl function. now I need to populate it with the data received from the http request. How do I pass data from a child to the parents function? hopefully thats the problem.